# How do you automate appium tests on Android with browser login?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, appium, ui-automation

I'm setting up test automation for an Android app using Appium.  I can launch the Android app, find elements, enter text and click buttons.  The issue I have is that my app has a user login, which requires launching a web browser to a web page from Identity Server (https://github.com/IdentityServer).  For discussion purposes, this is a web page with entry fields for login and password with a sign in button.

So the automated process is:

1. Launch app
2. Enter url for login page (i.e. identity server) in text field
3. Click save button (to save setting)
4. Click login button, which opens web browser to login page (after successful login, control returns to the app.)

Here is where I am stuck.  How can I use Appium to find the text controls and enter login and password, then find and click "Sign in" button for webpage (which will redirect back to the Android app under test and continue with remainder of automated app tests.)?

Appium's Inspector will only find a view from com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.  It does NOT find any of the browser elements.  Same with Android's UI Automator Viewer.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your context from native app to webview.

Here how I implemented it in tests.

1. In some Page Object files I keep Android contexts.

   ```
    ANDROID_CONTEXTS = {
        'webview': 'WEBVIEW_ru.myapp',
        'native': 'NATIVE_APP'
    }
   ```
2. In some tests I switch context from Native to Webview.

   ```
    @allure.link(url='https://jira.project.tech/browse/TEST-1', name='TEST-1 - Fill payment form')
    @allure.title('Fill payment form')
    def test_card_standard_1_month(appdriver):

        Paywall(appdriver).press_one_month_button()
        PaymentsPage(appdriver).select_card_payment()
        PaymentsPage(appdriver).press_payment_button()


        appdriver.switch_to.context(ANDROID_CONTEXTS['webview'])
        Payform(appdriver).fill_and_submit_payform()

        appdriver.switch_to.context(ANDROID_CONTEXTS['native'])

        assert SuccessPayment(appdriver).get_successful_payment_title_text() == 'Your subscription is successful!'
   ```

You can check all available contexts in your app. More info here -> http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/